# Is it possible to convert a full utf-8 url to a unique ID

Tags: php, unique-key

Is it possible to convert a path utf-8 in url to a short and fixed unique ID in php?

I want every time,same result.

for example this:

```
questions/صصثبصث/ask?q=asd$a=سیبث
```

to be something like this: `34Sdd6N`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRC32 is the most suitable option when we talk about performance. If you use MySQL/MariaDB as a DBMS, you may create `INT` column with `UNSIGNED` flag and it'll store CRC32 result fully in 4 bytes only per each url.

PHP has `crc32` function which accepts strings and has a very good dispersion of hashes, so you should not really care about duplicates.

You may also add `dechex` wrapper around your CRC32 result if you want to add ABCDEF letters to hash without database performance impact (and for sure use `hexdec` to convert it back).

Answer (score 0):

save url in the database table and add column "code" or other name like it to table . you can add random string for every insert url and so get url with this code . be carfull do not using duplicate code .

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to ask is basically **Hashing**. There are some function available for hashing in php also. One of such functions is available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). I hope you will find it useful.